# Seasonal index using Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table like this

```
Quarter   Q1         Q2        Q3     Q4
Cost     1.89      2.54      5.33     2.11
```

In tableau I need my result to be the seasonal index over q1 that is :

```
Quarter     Q1           Q2         Q3           Q4
Cost     1.89/1.89    2.54/1.89  5.33/1.89    2.11/1.89
```

How can I do this in an easy way in tableau?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Sum(Cost) use:

```
SUM(Cost) / LOOKUP(SUM(Cost),FIRST())
```

This will divide the cost values by the first quarter cost values. If you have multiple years, and want to divide by Q1 of each year, you need to be more creative. Something like:

```
SUM(Cost) / LOOKUP(SUM(COST),1-DATEPART('quarter',MAX([Date])))
```

Comment: Did not work! Says cannot mix aggregate and non aggregate argument!!

Comment: Still the second formula does not give me the desired output :(

Comment: Well, that's the best I can do if you don't give more details. What does your database looks like? What is exactly on your worksheet right now? Can you share a twbx? Did you even make an effort to try to understand what my formulas are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try table calculations like difference or percent difference and set it to compute suing table (across), relative to first.